# setting Borders.ColorIndex doesn't change the color

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to change the color of the borders in some cells.  Strangely, I'm able to change the border color in some sheets of the workbook, but on one sheet, either the border color won't change or only 2 of the border lines will change.  I've tried using:

```
testWorksheet.cells(row,column).Borders.ColorIndex=7
```

When I do this, the value for ColorIndex changes, as I'm able to display its new value in the Immediate window using

```
?testWorksheet.cells(row,column).Borders.ColorIndex
```

But the actual color of the border doesn't change.  This is a worksheet that gets copied from another workbook during another part of the script.  Is there some setting that would be preventing the color from displaying properly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try

```
    ActiveCell.Borders(xlEdgeLeft).ColorIndex = 7
    ActiveCell.Borders(xlEdgeRight).ColorIndex = 7
    ActiveCell.Borders(xlEdgeTop).ColorIndex = 7
    ActiveCell.Borders(xlEdgeBottom).ColorIndex = 7
```

Comment: Thanks!  I'm surprised that I have to iterate through all the borders like that, but it works.